# Bash: Download files from file list

Tags: bash

I have a file named files.txt with all files which I want download.

**files.txt**

```
http://file/to/download/IC_0000.tpl
http://file/to/download/IC_0001.tpl
```

If I use

```
cat files.txt | egrep -v "(^#.*|^$)" | xargs -n 1 wget
```

all files are downloaded.

But I dont know how to use If files.txt contains only files without http

**files.txt**

```
IC_0000.tpl
IC_0001.tpl
```

I have "wget" only with this paramter:

```
Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [-s|--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document FILE]
        [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off] [-P DIR]
        [--no-check-certificate] [-U|--user-agent AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...
```

Can you help me, please.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do the files all have the same URL?

Answer (score 12):

Simply try `wget -i files.txt` (see http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options)

If you don't have the host in the file, try:

```
for i in `cat files.txt`; do wget "${HOST}/${i}"; done
```

Comment: Url is still same. So seeking a solution that will files.txt files only without the whole path.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave it here...
for MacOSX

```
file_name=newMP3List.txt && cur_path=$(pwd) && split -l 50 $file_name PART && find . -name "PART*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I f osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd $cur_path && cat f | while read CMD; do curl -O \\\"\$CMD\\\"; done; rm f;\""
```

for linux

```
cat newMP3List.txt | while read CMD; do curl -O $CMD; done;
```

need to replace newMP3List.txt with your filename